# How do I make a string be printed every time a variable is used?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a quiz and I want it to ask you to continue and for the quiz taker to have to input (yes/no) every time the quiz reminds the quiz taker how many points they have.

```
print('Hello, and welcome to Yousif Abudeebs quiz!')
name=input('First of all, type your name.')
print('Alright', name, ', choose one of these 3 topics to be quizzed on!!\na) The Industrial Revolution\nb) Taxes and Insurance Policy\nc) Video Games')
choice=input()
if (choice) not in ('video games' ,'Video Games' ,'videogames' ,'Video Games' , 'VIDEO GAMES' , ' Video games' , 'c' , 'C'):
    print("ZZz, That must've been a mistake. You meant video games right?\noh yeah i love video games")
else: 
    print('Alright video games!!! I LOVE VIDEO GAMESSSSSS!!!!')
score=0
choice=input('Okay first question. When was the last time you showered?\na) Today \nc) Whats that?\nc) i forgor ☠️  ')
if (choice) in ('c' , 'C'):
    print("CORRECT! Gamers don't take showers. Why shower if I'm going to get sweaty on fortnite right after?")
    score += 1
else:
    print('WRONG YOU BAKA !!! GAMERS DO NOT TAKE SHOWERSSSS!!!')
print(('Your score=')+str(score))
```

I want the program to `input('Do you want to continue? Yes/No:')` every time the score is checked without me having to type it again.

Comment: put the whole thing in a loop. at the end of the loop ask the user if he/she wants to continue. then check if the answer is "no" to break the loop,  if you want to show the points then just print the score.

Comment: Can you show me exactly how to do that please? I'm not familiar with loops and how to associate it with a specific string

Comment: I'd then recommend you taking a python tutorial so you can learn the basics of the language

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in these ways -

1. Using loops -

   ```
   print('Hello, and welcome to Yousif Abudeebs quiz!')
   name=input('First of all, type your name.')
   print('Alright', name, ', choose one of these 3 topics to be quizzed on!!\na) The Industrial Revolution\nb) Taxes and Insurance Policy\nc) Video Games')
   choice=input()
   if (choice) not in ('video games' ,'Video Games' ,'videogames' ,'Video Games' , 'VIDEO GAMES' , ' Video games' , 'c' , 'C'):
       print("ZZz, That must've been a mistake. You meant video games right?\noh yeah i love video games")
   else: 
       print('Alright video games!!! I LOVE VIDEO GAMESSSSSS!!!!')
   score=0
   flag=True
   while flag:
       choice=input('Okay first question. When was the last time you showered?\na) Today \nc) Whats that?\nc) i forgor ☠️  ')
       if (choice) in ('c' , 'C'):
           print("CORRECT! Gamers don't take showers. Why shower if I'm going to get sweaty on fortnite right after?")
           score += 1
       else:
           print('WRONG YOU BAKA !!! GAMERS DO NOT TAKE SHOWERSSSS!!!')
       print(('Your score=')+str(score))
       here = input('Do you want to continue? Yes/No:')
       if(here=="No" or here=="NO" or here=="no" or here=="nO"):
           flag=False
   ```
2. Using functions -

   ```
   print('Hello, and welcome to Yousif Abudeebs quiz!')
   name=input('First of all, type your name.')
   print('Alright', name, ', choose one of these 3 topics to be quizzed on!!\na) The Industrial Revolution\nb) Taxes and Insurance Policy\nc) Video Games')
   choice=input()
   if (choice) not in ('video games' ,'Video Games' ,'videogames' ,'Video Games' , 'VIDEO GAMES' , ' Video games' , 'c' , 'C'):
       print("ZZz, That must've been a mistake. You meant video games right?\noh yeah i love video games")
   else: 
       print('Alright video games!!! I LOVE VIDEO GAMESSSSSS!!!!')
   score=0

   def New_Questions():
       print("new question")
       here()
       pass

   def here():
       ques = input('Do you want to continue? Yes/No:')
       if(ques=="No" or ques=="NO" or ques=="no" or ques=="nO"):
           print("Bye")
           exit()
       else:
           New_Questions()


   choice=input('Okay first question. When was the last time you showered?\na) Today \nc) Whats that?\nc) i forgor ☠️  ')
   if (choice) in ('c' , 'C'):
       print("CORRECT! Gamers don't take showers. Why shower if I'm going to get sweaty on fortnite right after?")
       score += 1
   else:
       print('WRONG YOU BAKA !!! GAMERS DO NOT TAKE SHOWERSSSS!!!')
   print(('Your score=')+str(score))
   here()
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).